# Is it possible to stream sequence of images as video with LIBVLC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libvlc

I'm not familiar with libvlc, I'm just wondering if it's possible to stream some sequece of images with LIBVLC.

Comment: It has been discussed here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995719/c-libvlc-create-stream-from-frames-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995719/c-libvlc-create-stream-from-frames-images)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible - at least with JPG-compressed images, or raw video.

MJPEG is just all of the individual JPGs concatenated together.. and raw video codecs will play arbitrary uncompressed streams.